# codeigniter how pass login session in all controller

Tags: session, codeigniter-3

how to pass login session user data  in my all controller pages:
i tried lot of codes but note working anything. please any one can help me.
also load session library session .it get error

```
Severity: Notice: Undefined variable: session_data

Filename: controllers/Banner.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aapkavyavahar\admin\application\controllers\Banner.php
Line: 11
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\aapkavyavahar\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

My login contoller:

```
    function login_validation()  
  {  

       $this->load->library('form_validation');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');  
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  
       if($this->form_validation->run())  
       {  
            //true  
            $username = $this->input->post('username');  
            $password = $this->input->post('password');  
            //model function  
            $this->load->model('main_model');  
            if($this->main_model->can_login($username, $password))  
            {  
                 $session_data = array(  
                      'username'     =>     $username  
                 );  
                 $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);  
                 redirect('login/enter');  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username or Password');  
                 redirect('login/index');  
            }  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            //false  
            $this->index();  
       }  
  }  
public function enter(){  
       if($this->session->userdata('username') != '')  
       {  
            $this->load->view('includes/dashlink');
            $this->load->view('includes/dashheader');
            $this->load->view('index');
            $this->load->view('includes/dashfooter');


       }  
       else  
       {  
            redirect(base_url() . 'login/index');  
       }  
  }  
public function logout() {

$this->session->sess_destroy();
$data['message_display'] = 'Successfully Logout';
$this->load->view('login', $data);

    }
```

Other controller :

```
   function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('session');
    if(!$this->session->userdata(' $session_data')){
    redirect(login);
    }
        }
```

Comment: Try changing `if(!$this->session->userdata(' $session_data')){` to `if(!$this->session->userdata('username')){`

Answer (score 1):

On creating the session you can give a name as below:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session_name',$session_data); //give session name
```

Checking the session:

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        if(!$this->session->userdata('session_name')){
           redirect(login);
        }
}
```

And also you can access the session data:

```
$data_session = $this->session->userdata('session_name');
$username = $data_session['username];
```

Comment: Please up vote and mark as right for future references.